# What does this notation mean in piano music?

Tags: piano, notation

All I've been able to find is that it is a up bow marking for string instruments and have no clue what it means for piano.
[image]

Comment: I consider the referred *duplicate* as not very lucky, since it implies, that this is a breath mark, which seems somewhat questionable for piano. Even the possible *cesura* is somewhat doubtful given the 16th note run of the solo instrument. I'll vote to re-open.

Comment: It will help to know what piece this is from - we can listen for clues.

Comment: Is it even for piano? To me it looks like it has three staves, and the two on top would be overlapping on the keyboard. It would fit soloist with piano accompaniment, and the mark would then be for the soloist.

Comment: I've voted to close as needing more details.  If you tell us what the piece is you'll get a good answer; otherwise, you'll only get speculation unless someone happens to recognize it.

Comment: @ojs Even in that case, though, I'd consider it a bit of a misprint, since it's more aligned with the second staff, and in the matching font size. Plus, if it refers to the top staff, it would seem to align with the second 16th of the second beat, which would be odd. Sometimes bowed instruments, with an impractically long slur as seen here, will add an up-bow or down-bow mark at some point during the slur, not intentionally aligned with any note, to mean "change the bow whenever convenient." That's more in orchestral settings, though, where the changes can be staggered, and

Comment: As an aside, it's fun to try and guess what instrument and what key!  I've put my money on violin and piano, key of Bb.

Comment: ... and is more often penciled than printed. If I wanted to print it, I might put the upbow in parentheses. And finally, it would probably go above the staff it referred to.

Comment: Since I've never seen this mark on classical solo piano music, I'd tend to echo @nuggethead's guess that it's a bowing marking for the top staff, which is for violin (or, conceivably, viola). :)

Comment: Why was this upvoted when so incomplete? Show the system of staves, first page, something with the instruments labeled.

Answer (score 1):

In itself it could be a breath mark.  But when you look at the solo instrument stave (apparently violin?) above the piano staves, that seems an unlikely place for the music to take a hiatus.   It could be a misplaced up-bow mark from that upper stave, though it seems to be sized to match the full-size piano staves rather than the cue-sized top stave.

All things considered, I'm pretty confident it's just a misprint.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to answer your question with a question, but are there other sustain pedal markings in the piano part, such as Ped. *?

If not, this is probably a phrase marking and a suggestion about pedalling in a reduced score or an accompanist part. If there are, then this is probably a typo as it would be very odd to mix in an informal marking with the correct ones. Typos happen.

No matter what, sheet music is intended to be interpreted and brought to life, and sometimes composers and music engravers will use various markings creatively to express their intent.

Comment: Welcome! Thanks for contributing, but when a question doesn't have enough information to be answered conclusively, sometimes it's best to wait and give the user a chance to edit.

Answer (score 0):

With three staves, I doubt it's written for the piano, but the closest thing I can think of in notation for the piano is that it's a marker for an accent. Now, admittedly, I haven't seen a 'V', but I wonder if it might be an 'unfilled' variant of a Staccatissimo?

[image: Upbow vs accents].

Comment: Thanks for contributing! Sometimes, when a question isn't clear enough to give a conclusive answer, it's best to wait, or to vote-to-close as lacking information. In this case, I've seen the opposite, "upside-down upbows," especially in French turn-of-the-century publications, but not upbow-as-accent.

Comment: A lot of piano music is written on three staves for clarity. Liszt did it regularly, and Aaron Copland's Variations for Piano comes to mind as well.